# When building tensorflow, error occurred in configure.py

Tags: python, tensorflow, bazel

I tried to build tensorflow r1.13 on a Japanese rental server called mixhost.
But following error occurred.
In configure.py, there is an error where bazel is running.

```
$ bash configure
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./configure.py", line 1701, in <module>
    main()
  File "./configure.py", line 1557, in main
    check_bazel_version('0.19.0', '0.21.0')
  File "./configure.py", line 457, in check_bazel_version
    ['bazel','--batch', '--bazelrc=/dev/null', 'version'])
  File "./configure.py", line 147, in run_shell
    output = subprocess.check_output(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 575, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['bazel', '--batch', '--bazelrc=/dev/null', 'version']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

The execution environment is as follows:

bazel 0.21.0
oracle jdk 1.8.0_231
Python 2.7.5

The result of ulimit -a is as follows:

```
$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) 200000
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 1029826
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) 200000
open files                      (-n) 100
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 35
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) 4194304
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

The contents of error file is as follows:

```
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Cannot create worker GC thread. Out of system resources.
# Possible reasons:
#   The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
#   The process is running with CompressedOops enabled, and the Java Heap may be blocking the growth of the native heap
# Possible solutions:
#   Reduce memory load on the system
#   Increase physical memory or swap space
#   Check if swap backing store is full
#   Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)
#   Decrease number of Java threads
#   Decrease Java thread stack sizes (-Xss)
#   Set larger code cache with -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
# This output file may be truncated or incomplete.
#
#  Out of Memory Error (workerManager.hpp:70), pid=167074, tid=167080
#
# JRE version:  (9.0.1+1) (build )
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (9.0.7.1+1, mixed mode, aot, tiered, compressed oops, parallel gc, linux-amd64)
# No core dump will be written. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#

---------------  S U M M A R Y ------------

Command Line: -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/home/nnnnnn/.cache/bazel/_bazel_nnnnnn/5d86588a5a5062a538adcc453bb6f4ca -XX:+UseParallelOldGC --add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED -Xverify:none -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/home/nnnnnn/.cache/bazel/_bazel_nnnnnn/5d86588a5a5062a538adcc453bb6f4ca/javalog.properties -Dcom.google.devtools.build.lib.util.LogHandlerQuerier.class=com.google.devtools.build.lib.util.SimpleLogHandler$HandlerQuerier -Djava.library.path=/home/nnnnnn/.cache/bazel/_bazel_nnnnnn/install/f6ca571514ebc1be8327564b4455aae2/_embedded_binaries/embedded_tools/jdk/lib/jli:/home/nnnnnn/.cache/bazel/_bazel_nnnnnn/install/f6ca571514ebc1be8327564b4455aae2/_embedded_binaries/embedded_tools/jdk/lib:/home/nnnnnn/.cache/bazel/_bazel_nnnnnn/install/f6ca571514ebc1be8327564b4455aae2/_embedded_binaries/embedded_tools/jdk/lib/server:/home/nnnnnn/.cache/bazel/_bazel_nnnnnn/install/f6ca571514ebc1be8327564b4455aae2/_embedded_binaries/ -Dfile.encoding=ISO-8859-1 /home/nnnnnn/.cache/bazel/_bazel_nnnnnn/install/f6ca571514ebc1be8327564b4455aae2/_embedded_binaries/A-server.jar --batch --connect_timeout_secs=30 --output_user_root=/home/nnnnnn/.cache/bazel/_bazel_nnnnnn --install_base=/home/nnnnnn/.cache/bazel/_bazel_nnnnnn/install/f6ca571514ebc1be8327564b4455aae2 --install_md5=f6ca571514ebc1be8327564b4455aae2 --output_base=/home/nnnnnn/.cache/bazel/_bazel_nnnnnn/5d86588a5a5062a538adcc453bb6f4ca --workspace_directory=/home/nnnnnn/tensorflow --default_system_javabase=/home/nnnnnn/jdk1.8.0_231 --deep_execroot --expand_configs_in_place --idle_server_tasks --noexperimental_oom_more_eagerly --experimental_oom_more_eagerly_threshold=100 --write_command_log --nowatchfs --nofatal_event_bus_exceptions --client_debug=false --product_name=Bazel --option_sources=batch: version --startup_time=4 --binary_path=/home/nnnnnn/bin/bazel --rc_source=client --default_override=0:common=--isatty=1 --default_override=0:common=--terminal_columns=136 --rc_source=/home/nnnnnn/tensorflow/.bazelrc --rc_source=/dev/null --default_override=1:build:nonccl=--define=no_nccl_support=true --default_override=1:build:noignite=--define=no_ignite_support=true --default_override=1:build:nokafka=--define=no_kafka_support=true --default_override=1:build:download_clang_use_lld=--linkopt=-fuse-ld=lld --default_override=1:build:mkl_open_source_only=--define=build_with_mkl_dnn_only=true --default_override=1:build:mkl_open_source_only=--define=build_with_mkl=true --default_override=1:build:mkl_open_source_only=--define=enable_mkl=true --default_override=1:build:cuda=--crosstool_top=@local_config_cuda//crosstool:toolchain --default_override=1:build:cuda=--define=using_cuda=true --default_override=1:build:cuda=--define=using_cuda_nvcc=true --default_override=1:build:monolithic=--define --default_override=1:build:monolithic=framework_shared_object=false --default_override=1:build:android_arm64=--config=android --default_override=1:build:android_arm64=--cpu=arm64-v8a --default_override=1:build:android_arm64=--fat_apk_cpu=arm64-v8a --default_override=1:build:download_clang=--crosstool_top=@local_config_download_clang//:toolchain --default_override=1:build:download_clang=--define=using_clang=true --default_override=1:build:rocm=--crosstool_top=@local_config_rocm//crosstool:toolchain --default_override=1:build:rocm=--define=using_rocm=true --default_override=1:build:rocm=--define=using_rocm_hipcc=true --default_override=1:build:android_arm=--config=android --default_override=1:build:android_arm=--cpu=armeabi-v7a --default_override=1:build:android_arm=--fat_apk_cpu=armeabi-v7a --default_override=1:build:verbs=--define=with_verbs_support=true --default_override=1:build:android=--crosstool_top=//external:android/crosstool --default_override=1:build:android=--host_crosstool_top=@bazel_tools//tools/cpp:toolchain --default_override=1:build:cuda_clang=--crosstool_top=@local_config_cuda//crosstool:toolchain --default_override=1:build:cuda_clang=--define=using_cuda=true --default_override=1:build:cuda_clang=--define=using_cuda_clang=true --default_override=1:build:cuda_clang=--define=using_clang=true --default_override=1:build:mkl=--define=build_with_mkl=true --default_override=1:build:mkl=--define=enable_mkl=true --default_override=1:build:mkl=-c --default_override=1:build:mkl=opt --default_override=1:build:sycl=--crosstool_top=@local_config_sycl//crosstool:toolchain --default_override=1:build:sycl=--define=using_sycl=true --default_override=1:build:sycl=--define=using_trisycl=false --default_override=1:build:ngraph=--define=with_ngraph_support=true --default_override=1:build:sycl_asan=--crosstool_top=@local_config_sycl//crosstool:toolchain --default_override=1:build:sycl_asan=--define=using_sycl=true --default_override=1:build:sycl_asan=--define=using_trisycl=false --default_override=1:build:sycl_asan=--copt --default_override=1:build:sycl_asan=-fno-omit-frame-pointer --default_override=1:build:sycl_asan=--copt --default_override=1:build:sycl_asan=-fsanitize-coverage=3 --default_override=1:build:sycl_asan=--copt --default_override=1:build:sycl_asan=-DGPR_NO_DIRECT_SYSCALLS --default_override=1:build:sycl_asan=--linkopt --default_override=1:build:sycl_asan=-fPIC --default_override=1:build:sycl_asan=--linkopt --default_override=1:build:sycl_asan=-fsanitize=address --default_override=1:build:sycl_nodouble=--crosstool_top=@local_config_sycl//crosstool:toolchain --default_override=1:build:sycl_nodouble=--define=using_sycl=true --default_override=1:build:sycl_nodouble=--cxxopt --default_override=1:build:sycl_nodouble=-DTENSORFLOW_SYCL_NO_DOUBLE --default_override=1:build:sycl_trisycl=--crosstool_top=@local_config_sycl//crosstool:toolchain --default_override=1:build:sycl_trisycl=--define=using_sycl=true --default_override=1:build:sycl_trisycl=--define=using_trisycl=true --default_override=1:build:nohdfs=--define=no_hdfs_support=true --default_override=1:build:dynamic_kernels=--define=dynamic_loaded_kernels=true --default_override=1:build:dynamic_kernels=--copt=-DAUTOLOAD_DYNAMIC_KERNELS --default_override=1:build=--define --default_override=1:build=framework_shared_object=true --default_override=1:build=--define=use_fast_cpp_protos=true --default_override=1:build=--define=allow_oversize_protos=true --default_override=1:build=--spawn_strategy=standalone --default_override=1:build=--genrule_strategy=standalone --default_override=1:build=-c --default_override=1:build=opt --default_override=1:build=--define=grpc_no_ares=true --default_override=1:build=--define=PREFIX=/usr --default_override=1:build=--define=LIBDIR=$(PREFIX)/lib --default_override=1:build=--define=INCLUDEDIR=$(PREFIX)/include --default_override=1:build:gdr=--define=with_gdr_support=true --default_override=1:build:noaws=--define=no_aws_support=true --default_override=1:build:nogcp=--define=no_gcp_support=true --client_cwd=/home/nnnnnn/tensorflow

Host: Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6130 CPU @ 2.10GHz, 64 cores, 251G, Linux
Time: Wed Dec  4 07:59:40 2019 JST elapsed time: 0 seconds (0d 0h 0m 0s)

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00007f1818014000):  JavaThread "Unknown thread" [_thread_in_vm, id=167080, stack(0x00007f1820d82000,0x00007f1820e81000)]

Stack: [0x00007f1820d82000,0x00007f1820e81000],  sp=0x00007f1820e7f520,  free space=1013k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, A=aot compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [libjvm.so+0xc7ae63]  VMError::report_and_die(int, char const*, char const*, __va_list_tag*, Thread*, unsigned char*, void*, void*, char const*, int, unsigned long)+0x163
V  [libjvm.so+0xc7b9b5]  VMError::report_and_die(Thread*, char const*, int, unsigned long, VMErrorType, char const*, __va_list_tag*)+0x45
V  [libjvm.so+0x612d7a]  report_vm_out_of_memory(char const*, int, unsigned long, VMErrorType, char const*, ...)+0xea
V  [libjvm.so+0x7226b1]  GCTaskManager::add_workers(bool)+0x261
V  [libjvm.so+0x722baa]  GCTaskManager::initialize()+0x46a
V  [libjvm.so+0xadfddc]  ParallelScavengeHeap::initialize()+0x2ac
V  [libjvm.so+0xc458ad]  Universe::initialize_heap()+0x3d
V  [libjvm.so+0xc45d74]  universe_init()+0x54
V  [libjvm.so+0x7a1fda]  init_globals()+0x5a
V  [libjvm.so+0xc2a252]  Threads::create_vm(JavaVMInitArgs*, bool*)+0x302
V  [libjvm.so+0x7dccac]  JNI_CreateJavaVM+0x7c
C  [libjli.so+0x3f24]  JavaMain+0x84
C  [libpthread.so.0+0x7ea5]  start_thread+0xc5


---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )

Other Threads:

[error occurred during error reporting (printing all threads), id 0xe0000001]

VM state:not at safepoint (not fully initialized)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap address: 0x0000000080000000, size: 2048 MB, Compressed Oops mode: Non-zero based: 0x0000000080000000
Narrow klass base: 0x0000000000000000, Narrow klass shift: 0

GC Heap History (0 events):
No events

Deoptimization events (0 events):
No events

Classes redefined (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (0 events):
No events

Events (0 events):
No events


Dynamic libraries:
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 8075607596                         /home/nnnnnn/.cache/bazel/_bazel_nnnnnn/install/f6ca571514ebc1be8327564b4455aae2/_embedded_binaries/embedded_tools/jdk/bin/java
00601000-00602000 rw-p 00001000 08:04 8075607596                         /home/nnnnnn/.cache/bazel/_bazel_nnnnnn/install/f6ca571514ebc1be8327564b4455aae2/_embedded_binaries/embedded_tools/jdk/bin/java
00963000-00984000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
80000000-100000000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f17a0000000-7f17a0021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f17a0021000-7f17a4000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 

...

7f18093a2000-7f1809612000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1809612000-7f1810774000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1810774000-7f1818000000 r--s 00000000 08:04 3250633997                 /home/nnnnnn/.cache/bazel/_bazel_nnnnnn/install/f6ca571514ebc1be8327564b4455aae2/_embedded_binaries/embedded_tools/jdk/lib/modules
7f1818000000-7f1818378000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1818378000-7f181c000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0

...

7f181dab2000-7f181dab7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f181dab7000-7f181db9a000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f181db9a000-7f181dba5000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 3250584762                 /home/nnnnnn/.cache/bazel/_bazel_nnnnnn/install/f6ca571514ebc1be8327564b4455aae2/_embedded_binaries/embedded_tools/jdk/lib/libjimage.so

...

7f181e3e5000-7f181e3e7000 rw-p 0000d000 08:04 3250633992                 /home/nnnnnn/.cache/bazel/_bazel_nnnnnn/install/f6ca571514ebc1be8327564b4455aae2/_embedded_binaries/embedded_tools/jdk/lib/libverify.so
7f181e3e7000-7f181e3ee000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 2684731575                 /lib64/librt-2.17.so

...

7f181e5ee000-7f181e5ef000 rw-p 00007000 08:04 2684731575                 /lib64/librt-2.17.so
7f181e5ef000-7f181e604000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 2766674179                 /lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.5-20150702.so.1

...

7f181e804000-7f181e805000 rw-p 00015000 08:04 2766674179                 /lib64/libgcc_s-4.8.5-20150702.so.1
7f181e805000-7f181e906000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 2684712496                 /lib64/libm-2.17.so

...

7f181eb06000-7f181eb07000 rw-p 00101000 08:04 2684712496                 /lib64/libm-2.17.so
7f181eb07000-7f181ebf0000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 2684354844                 /lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.19

...

7f181edf8000-7f181edfa000 rw-p 000f1000 08:04 2684354844                 /lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
7f181edfa000-7f181ee0f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f181ee0f000-7f181fd12000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 4839940158                 /home/nnnnnn/.cache/bazel/_bazel_nnnnnn/install/f6ca571514ebc1be8327564b4455aae2/_embedded_binaries/embedded_tools/jdk/lib/server/libjvm.so

...

7f181ffe2000-7f1820017000 rw-p 00fd3000 08:04 4839940158                 /home/nnnnnn/.cache/bazel/_bazel_nnnnnn/install/f6ca571514ebc1be8327564b4455aae2/_embedded_binaries/embedded_tools/jdk/lib/server/libjvm.so
7f1820017000-7f1820060000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1820060000-7f1820223000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 2684518041                 /lib64/libc-2.17.so

...

7f1820427000-7f1820429000 rw-p 001c7000 08:04 2684518041                 /lib64/libc-2.17.so
7f1820429000-7f182042e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f182042e000-7f1820430000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 2684712494                 /lib64/libdl-2.17.so

...

7f1820631000-7f1820632000 rw-p 00003000 08:04 2684712494                 /lib64/libdl-2.17.so
7f1820632000-7f1820640000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 3762776887                 /home/nnnnnn/.cache/bazel/_bazel_nnnnnn/install/f6ca571514ebc1be8327564b4455aae2/_embedded_binaries/embedded_tools/jdk/lib/jli/libjli.so
7f1820640000-7f182083f000 ---p 0000e000 08:04 3762776887                 /home/nnnnnn/.cache/bazel/_bazel_nnnnnn/install/f6ca571514ebc1be8327564b4455aae2/_embedded_binaries/embedded_tools/jdk/lib/jli/libjli.so
7f182083f000-7f1820840000 rw-p 0000d000 08:04 3762776887                 /home/nnnnnn/.cache/bazel/_bazel_nnnnnn/install/f6ca571514ebc1be8327564b4455aae2/_embedded_binaries/embedded_tools/jdk/lib/jli/libjli.so
7f1820840000-7f1820857000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 2684731536                 /lib64/libpthread-2.17.so

...

7f1820a57000-7f1820a58000 rw-p 00017000 08:04 2684731536                 /lib64/libpthread-2.17.so
7f1820a58000-7f1820a5c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1820a5c000-7f1820a71000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 2684355277                 /lib64/libz.so.1.2.7

...

7f1820c71000-7f1820c72000 rw-p 00015000 08:04 2684355277                 /lib64/libz.so.1.2.7
7f1820c72000-7f1820c94000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 2766674182                 /lib64/ld-2.17.so
7f1820d35000-7f1820d3f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1820d3f000-7f1820d4b000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1820d4b000-7f1820d80000 r--s 00000000 08:04 4294976241                 /var/db/nscd/passwd
7f1820d80000-7f1820d81000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 

...

7f1820e87000-7f1820e88000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1820e88000-7f1820e90000 rw-s 00000000 08:04 9672327340                 /tmp/hsperfdata_nnnnnn/167074
7f1820e90000-7f1820e91000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1820e91000-7f1820e92000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1820e92000-7f1820e93000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1820e93000-7f1820e94000 r--p 00021000 08:04 2766674182                 /lib64/ld-2.17.so
7f1820e94000-7f1820e95000 rw-p 00022000 08:04 2766674182                 /lib64/ld-2.17.so
7f1820e95000-7f1820e96000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffca7e95000-7ffca7eb9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffca7f3c000-7ffca7f3e000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/home/nnnnnn/.cache/bazel/_bazel_nnnnnn/5d86588a5a5062a538adcc453bb6f4ca -XX:+UseParallelOldGC --add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED -Xverify:none -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/home/nnnnnn/.cache/bazel/_bazel_nnnnnn/5d86588a5a5062a538adcc453bb6f4ca/javalog.properties -Dcom.google.devtools.build.lib.util.LogHandlerQuerier.class=com.google.devtools.build.lib.util.SimpleLogHandler$HandlerQuerier -Djava.library.path=/home/nnnnnn/.cache/bazel/_bazel_nnnnnn/install/f6ca571514ebc1be8327564b4455aae2/_embedded_binaries/embedded_tools/jdk/lib/jli:/home/nnnnnn/.cache/bazel/_bazel_nnnnnn/install/f6ca571514ebc1be8327564b4455aae2/_embedded_binaries/embedded_tools/jdk/lib:/home/nnnnnn/.cache/bazel/_bazel_nnnnnn/install/f6ca571514ebc1be8327564b4455aae2/_embedded_binaries/embedded_tools/jdk/lib/server:/home/nnnnnn/.cache/bazel/_bazel_nnnnnn/install/f6ca571514ebc1be8327564b4455aae2/_embedded_binaries/ -Dfile.encoding=ISO-8859-1 
java_command: /home/nnnnnn/.cache/bazel/_bazel_nnnnnn/install/f6ca571514ebc1be8327564b4455aae2/_embedded_binaries/A-server.jar --batch --connect_timeout_secs=30 --output_user_root=/home/nnnnnn/.cache/bazel/_bazel_nnnnnn --install_base=/home/nnnnnn/.cache/bazel/_bazel_nnnnnn/install/f6ca571514ebc1be8327564b4455aae2 --install_md5=f6ca571514ebc1be8327564b4455aae2 --output_base=/home/nnnnnn/.cache/bazel/_bazel_nnnnnn/5d86588a5a5062a538adcc453bb6f4ca --workspace_directory=/home/nnnnnn/tensorflow --default_system_javabase=/home/nnnnnn/jdk1.8.0_231 --deep_execroot --expand_configs_in_place --idle_server_tasks --noexperimental_oom_more_eagerly --experimental_oom_more_eagerly_threshold=100 --write_command_log --nowatchfs --nofatal_event_bus_exceptions --client_debug=false --product_name=Bazel --option_sources=batch: version --startup_time=4 --binary_path=/home/nnnnnn/bin/bazel --rc_source=client --default_override=0:common=--isatty=1 --default_override=0:common=--terminal_columns=136 --rc_source=/home/nnnnnn/tensorflow/.bazelrc --rc_source=/dev/null --default_override=1:build:nonccl=--define=no_nccl_support=true --default_override=1:build:noignite=--define=no_ignite_support=true --default_override=1:build:nokafka=--define=no_kafka_support=true --default_override=1:build:download_clang_use_lld=--linkopt=-fuse-ld=lld --default_override=1:build:mkl_open_source_only=--define=build_with_mkl_dnn_only=true --default_override=1:build:mkl_open_source_only=--define=build_with_mkl=true --default_override=1:build:mkl_open_source_only=--define=enable_mkl=true --default_override=1:build:cuda=--crosstool_top=@local_config_cuda//crosstool:toolchain --default_override=1:build:cuda=--define=using_cuda=true --default_override=1:build:cuda=--define=using_cuda_nvcc=true --default_override=1:build:monolithic=--define --default_override=1:build:monolithic=framework_shared_object=false --default_override=1:build:android_arm64=--config=android --default_override=1:build:and
java_class_path (initial): /home/nnnnnn/.cache/bazel/_bazel_nnnnnn/install/f6ca571514ebc1be8327564b4455aae2/_embedded_binaries/A-server.jar
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Logging:
Log output configuration:
#0: stdout all=warning uptime,level,tags
#1: stderr all=off uptime,level,tags

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=/home/nnnnnn/jdk1.8.0_231
CLASSPATH=.:/home/nnnnnn/jdk1.8.0_231/jre/lib:/home/nnnnnn/jdk1.8.0_231/lib:/home/nnnnnn/jdk1.8.0_231/lib/tools.jar
PATH=/home/nnnnnn/.pyenv/libexec:/home/nnnnnn/.pyenv/plugins/python-build/bin:/home/nnnnnn/.pyenv/plugins/pyenv-virtualenv/bin:/home/nnnnnn/.pyenv/plugins/pyenv-virtualenv/shims:/home/nnnnnn/.pyenv/shims:/home/nnnnnn/.pyenv/bin:/home/nnnnnn/usr/local/bin:/home/nnnnnn/usr/local/lib:/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib/path-bin:/usr/local/jdk/bin:/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/root/bin:/opt/bin:/opt/cpanel/composer/bin:/home/nnnnnn/jdk1.8.0_231/bin:/home/nnnnnn/.local/bin:/home/nnnnnn/bin
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/nnnnnn/usr/local/lib

Signal Handlers:
SIGSEGV: [libjvm.so+0xc7bf20], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGBUS: [libjvm.so+0xc7bf20], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGFPE: [libjvm.so+0xc7bf20], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGPIPE: [libjvm.so+0xab5a30], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGXFSZ: [libjvm.so+0xab5a30], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGILL: [libjvm.so+0xc7bf20], sa_mask[0]=11111111011111111101111111111110, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGUSR2: [libjvm.so+0xab5640], sa_mask[0]=00000000000000000000000000000000, sa_flags=SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO
SIGHUP: SIG_IGN, sa_mask[0]=00000000000000000000000000000000, sa_flags=none
SIGINT: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=00000000000000000000000000000000, sa_flags=none
SIGTERM: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=00000000000000000000000000000000, sa_flags=none
SIGQUIT: SIG_DFL, sa_mask[0]=00000000000000000000000000000000, sa_flags=none


---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS:Linux
uname:Linux 3.10.0-962.3.2.lve1.5.25.12.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Jun 27 08:04:52 EDT 2019 x86_64
libc:glibc 2.17 NPTL 2.17 
rlimit: STACK 8192k, CORE 0k, NPROC 35, NOFILE 100, AS 4194304k
load average:6.99 6.73 6.61

/proc/meminfo:
MemTotal:       263692488 kB
MemFree:         6833232 kB
MemAvailable:   192997028 kB
Buffers:           10304 kB
Cached:         196497884 kB
SwapCached:        41936 kB
Active:         92962708 kB
Inactive:       139952396 kB
Active(anon):   38340360 kB
Inactive(anon):  4522968 kB
Active(file):   54622348 kB
Inactive(file): 135429428 kB
Unevictable:           0 kB
Mlocked:               0 kB
SwapTotal:      16777212 kB
SwapFree:       16594624 kB
Dirty:               824 kB
Writeback:             0 kB
AnonPages:      36374504 kB
Mapped:           428476 kB
Shmem:           6456364 kB
Slab:           17731408 kB
SReclaimable:   13412464 kB
SUnreclaim:      4318944 kB
KernelStack:       26656 kB
PageTables:       147344 kB
NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
Bounce:                0 kB
WritebackTmp:          0 kB
CommitLimit:    148623456 kB
Committed_AS:   57371124 kB
VmallocTotal:   34359738367 kB
VmallocUsed:     1881284 kB
VmallocChunk:   34223895240 kB
HardwareCorrupted:     0 kB
AnonHugePages:         0 kB
CmaTotal:              0 kB
CmaFree:               0 kB
Tcache:                0 kB
Tswap:                 0 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
DirectMap4k:      513856 kB
DirectMap2M:    25313280 kB
DirectMap1G:    244318208 kB


CPU:total 64 (initial active 64) (16 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 85 stepping 4, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, avx2, aes, clmul, erms, rtm, 3dnowpref, lzcnt, ht, tsc, tscinvbit, bmi1, bmi2, adx, fma
CPU Model and flags from /proc/cpuinfo:
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6130 CPU @ 2.10GHz
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu cpuid_faulting pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid dca sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch epb cat_l3 cdp_l3 intel_ppin intel_pt ssbd mba ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 hle avx2 bmi2 erms invpcid rtm cqm rdt_a avx512f avx512dq rdseed adx smap clflushopt clwb avx512cd avx512bw avx512vl xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 cqm_llc cqm_occup_llc cqm_mbm_total cqm_mbm_local dtherm ida arat pln pts pku ospke spec_ctrl intel_stibp flush_l1d

Memory: 4k page, physical 263692488k(6828592k free), swap 16777212k(16594624k free)

vm_info: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (9.0.7.1+1) for linux-amd64 JRE (9.0.7.1+1), built on Apr  6 2018 13:59:40 by "tester" with gcc 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)

END.
```

An error occurred when bazel was started on the command line.

```
$ bazel --batch --bazelrc=/dev/null version
[0.041s][warning][os,thread] Failed to start thread - pthread_create failed (EAGAIN) for attributes: 
stacksize: 1024k, guardsize: 4k, detached.
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Cannot create worker GC thread. Out of system resources.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/nnnnnn/hs_err_pid229018.log
```

When I started bazel with the option added, it worked fine.

```
$ bazel --host_jvm_args="-XX:ParallelGCThreads=1" --host_jvm_args="-Xmx64m" --batch --bazelrc=/dev/null version
WARNING: --batch mode is deprecated. Please instead explicitly shut down your Bazel server using the command "bazel shutdown".
INFO: Invocation ID: 270fb316-12c0-462f-bc91-a59c29c41c27
Build label: 0.21.0
Build target: bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/bazel/BazelServer_deploy.jar
Build time: Wed Dec 19 12:58:44 2018 (1545224324)
Build timestamp: 1545224324
Build timestamp as int: 1545224324
```

However, a similar error occurred when modifying configure.py and running bash configure.

```
$ bash configure
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./configure.py", line 1702, in <module>
    main()
  File "./configure.py", line 1558, in main
    check_bazel_version('0.19.0', '0.21.0')
  File "./configure.py", line 457, in check_bazel_version
    ['bazel','--host_jvm_args="-XX:ParallelGCThreads=1"','--host_jvm_args="-Xmx64m"','--batch', '--bazelrc=/dev/null', 'version'])
  File "./configure.py", line 147, in run_shell
    output = subprocess.check_output(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 575, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['bazel', '--host_jvm_args="-XX:ParallelGCThreads=1"', '--host_jvm_args="-Xmx64m"', '--batch','--bazelrc=/dev/null', 'version']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Could you please help me?
Thank you.

Comment: Have you found the solution to this problem?